# 4 same unhelpful errors for every error I receive in c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, spdlog, fmt

I am using spdlog, opengl, glad, and glfw in my project. No matter what error I am receiving, it is ALWAYS preceded by the 4 same errors. For example, let's say I have the following code:

`std::cout << "sup";`

then it will run perfectly. Okay now, let's say I have a typo and I do this:

`std:cout<< "sup";`

I get the following errors:

[image]

Here are the first 2 errors.. they redirect to FMT core.h file

[image]

and then the last two redirect to FMT format.h

[image]

Does anyone know why this could be happening? it is not made or break, whenever I have an error and I fix it these go away but it's just annoying and I would like to understand why.

Comment: According to the [link](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/375887/intellisense-generates-error-e1866-when-using-c-at.html) , IntelliSense generates error E1866 when using C++ attribute [[deprecated]] in alias declaration is a issue, I suggest you could try to install the Visual Studio 2019 RC from https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/ . And you could also fix it by commenting FMT_DEPRECATED in core.h and format.h (lines where VS pointed to an error).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks as though this PR will fix your issue? 
https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt/pull/1279 
Maybe just update fmt to the latest version?